# How do I write a Windows script to search for the newest file in multiple directories and then attach those files to an email?

Tags: windows, batch-file

As a complete newbie I would like some help in trying to generate a batch script to search through two specific directories to find the latest version of some files (*.csv) and then attach those files to an email.

I am intending to run this through Windows Task Scheduler but would be open to hearing other solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "root=%userprofile%\documents"
set "dest=%temp%"
set "patt=.csv"

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /ad /s "%root%"') do (
    pushd %%i
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%j in (%patt%) do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%k in ('dir /b /a-d /od /tw *%%j 2^>nul') do set "fname=%%k"
        if defined fname xcopy /d /y "%%i\!fname!" "%dest%"
    )
    endlocal
    popd
)
endlocal
```

Set `root` to the folder that contains the CSV subfolders.